# CXF JAX-RS how to sign XML message (using XAdES-T)

Tags: jaxb, jax-rs, xml-signature, cxfrs, xades

I am trying to build **REST service** using Apache CXF.
One of the requirement is to **sign XML** using **XAdES-T** standard.

I was going over
[jax-rs-xml-security](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-xml-security.html)
and made it to sign XML document.

How can I add a timestamp to the signature?
https://www.w3.org/TR/XAdES/

Is it possible to do XAdES-T using CXF?

Demo project can be found: https://gitlab.com/SamaraIT/orders-cxf

Please advice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are libraries which can be used to sign XML messages using **XAdES** standard, such as:

- [xades4j](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j)
- [Digital Signature Service](https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/DSS/webapp-demo/doc/dss-documentation.html)